# Python Dramatiq - Accessing message id from actor method

Tags: python, dramatiq

How can I access message id from within the actor method? I want to see which id is getting processed for logging purpose

```py
@dramatiq.actor
def fn(x, y):
    # log the message id
    return x+y
```